# How can I define proxy settings in karate-config.js file?

Tags: karate

I'm trying with Karate behind my office network which is using proxy. But the configure statement didn't work. In home network. it works perfectly fine.

The configure statement : didn't work for our proxy. `karate.configure('proxy', 'https:/my.proxy.host:8080');`

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from these issues [#502](https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/502) and [this other Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56555491/143475) question, this works for others. So you will have to figure this out and it will help everyone if you debug this on the Java side if possible. Maybe you are missing authentication for your environment.

You can try switching to `karate-jersey` from `karate-apache` or vice-versa and see if that changes anything. Else unless you provide a way to replicate, we can't help - but this is indeed difficult for a proxy: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue