# Karate: set HTTP and HTTPS proxy in feature file

Tags: karate

I am trying to set proxy in the feature file, but facing issue while execution

While running curl command for my API, I do,

```
set HTTP_PROXY = http://proxy.company.net:1212
```

```
set HTTPS_PROXY = http://proxy.company.net:1212
```

And then executing the curl command works:

```
curl -X POST  'https://url.com/endpoint' -H 'accept: application/json -d 'id=123'
```

My karate feature file looks like below:

```
Feature: Test

Background:
* configure connectTimeout = 30000
* configure proxy = { uri: 'http://proxy.company.net:1212'}

Scenario: get data
* configure headers = {'accept': 'application/json}
Given url 'https://url.com/endpoint'
And request {id: '123'}
When method post
Then status 200
```

I was looking into the documentation but was unable to find the syntax if I can get to set HTTP and HTTPS proxy from the feature file.

Answer (score 0):

I lack information about this, so please contribute some research and code if possible.

Meanwhile see if you can do this by setting Java / JVM settings: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/71

Also refer other answers such as this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56897037/143475

Comment: Thanks, May be I am looking for a way to do set HTTPS_PROXY = http://proxy.company.net:1212  through karate

Comment: @NachiK let us know what you find :)

Comment: The strange part is the setting of proxy through command prompt and running curl works, but I am looking for a way to access an external api which requires company proxy to be initially setup

Comment: May be my first comment was not fully edited. I meant I am looking for an option where I can perform HTTP_PROXY = http://proxy.company.net:1212 and HTTPS_PROXY = http://proxy.company.net:1212 in the configure proxy option

Comment: @NachiK maybe one of them is enough ? since no one else has this issue for the last 2 years, maybe it is a non-issue. anyway I want to make it clear that it is not a priority for me, and we really need the community to help with edge cases

Comment: Ok got it.. may be I thought my question was not clear. So I tried the same using the python requests module and this is how it worked. import requests; proxyDict = {"http": "http://proxy.company.net:1212", "https": "http://proxy.company.net:1212"};.    r = requests.post(url, data={}, headers={}, proxies = proxyDict). So thought this would be available in karate too

Comment: Just a quick question - is it only possible to set the URI of the HTTPS proxy in karate? I know HTTP works